# Error : non-payable method cannot override value

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity

**Trying to call a mint method in a smart contract deployed:**

```
function mint(uint256 _id) public payable{
    _safeMint(msg.sender, _id);
}
```

**Testing Code:**

```
beforeEach(async() => {
  const transaction = await ethDaddy.connect(owner1).mint(ID, { value: AMOUNT})
  await transaction.wait();
})
```

**Error:**

```
 Error: non-payable method cannot override value (operation="overrides.value", value={"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x8ac7230489e80000"}, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.7.0)
```

[image: ETHDaddy.sol]

[image: ETHDaddy.js Testing File]

Comment: Seems like your ABI JSON doesn't reflect the `payable` modifier. Can you post your definition of the `mint()` function in the ABI?

Comment: @PetrHejda I debugged my code and found out that the issue was with constructor method where I hadn't declared msg.sender as payable. I have answered my question below. Thanks for looking into my issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, after re-analyzing my code for hours of searching, I realized where the fix had to be done. The **msg.sender** variable had to be declared as payable as well, In the constructor method:

```
constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol) ERC721(_name, _symbol)
{
    owner = payable(msg.sender); // This had be declared as payable as well
}
```